# Firebase Functions and Express: listen to firestore data live

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a website that runs its frontend of `Firebase Hosting` and its server which is written using `node.js` and `Express` on `Firebase Functions`

What I want to have redirect links from my website so I can map for example `mywebsite.com/youtube` to my youtube channel. the way I am creating these links is from my admin panel, and adding them to my Firestore database.

My data is roughly something like this:

[image]

The first way I approached this, is by querying my Firestore database on every request, but that is heavily expensive and slow.

Another way I tried to approach this is by setting some kind of background listener to the Firestore database which will always provide up to date data. but unfortunately that did not work because `Firebase Functions` suspends the main function when the current request execution ends.

lastly, which is the most convenience way, I configured an api route, which will be called from my `Admin Panel` when any change happens to the data, and I would save the new data to some json file. I tried this on my local but it did not work on production because appearently `Firebase Functions` is a `Read-only` system, so we can't edit any files after they are deployed. after some research I found out that `Firebase Functions` allows writing to the `tmp` directory, so I went forward with this, and tried deploying it. but again, `Firebase Functions` was resetting the `tmp` folder when some request execution ends.

here is my api request code which updates the `utm_data.json` file in the `tmp` directory:

```js
// my firestore provider
const db = require('../db');

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os')

const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

const updateUrlsAPI = (req, res) => {
    // we wanna get the utm list from firestore, and update the file 
    // tmp/utm_data.json

    // query data from firestore
    db.collection('utmLinks').get().then(async function(querySnapshot) {
        try {
            // get the path to `tmp` folder depending on
            // the os running this program
            let tmpFolderName = os.tmpdir()

            // create `tmp` directory if not exists
            await mkdirp(tmpFolderName)

            let docsData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())

            let tmpFilePath = tmpFolderName + '/utm_data.json'

            let strData = JSON.stringify(docsData)
            fs.writeFileSync(tmpFilePath, strData)

            res.send('200')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error while updating utm_data.json: ", error)
            res.send(error)
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my code for reading the `utm_data.json` file on an incoming request:

```js
const readUrlsFromJson = (req, res) => {

    var url = req.path.split('/');
    // the url will be in the format of: 'mywebsite.com/routeName'
    var routeName = url[1];

    try {
        // read the file ../tmp/utm_data.json
        // {
        //   'createdAt': Date
        //   'creatorEmail': string
        //   'name': string
        //   'url': string
        // }
        // our [routeName] should match [name] of the doc
        let tmpFolderName = os.tmpdir()

        let tmpFilePath = tmpFolderName + '/utm_data.json'

        // read links list file and assign it to the `utms` variable
        let utms = require(tmpFilePath)

        if (!utms || !utms.length) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // find the link matching the routeName
        let utm = utms.find(utm => utm.name == routeName)

        if (!utm) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // if we found the doc,
        // then we'll redirect to the url
        res.redirect(utm.url)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, and if not, what is an optimal solution for this case?

Comment: Allow me to ask: Can you share the documentation used to create the code, and do you get an error while executing the code? Do you want to implement the 3rd option (the most convenient way) or you only need a suggestion?, Do you want to avoid resetting the `tmp` folder when the request execution ends?

Comment: Hi @AndresFiescoCasasola, Thanks for taking the time to reply. Can you please explain by what you mean by `Can you share the documentation used to create the code`. I am not having any error running the code, it runs just fine, I just keep getting `folder does not exist` error for the `tmp` folder after the Firebase Functions removes that folder. As my experience is mostly in the Front end field, I can't tell what is the best way, so I am open to any suggestion of how to do this. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey @Adnan, were you able to checkout my answer? Let me know if I've missed anything from the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the Firestore listener in [global scope](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_scope_versus_global_scope). From the documentation,

> The global scope in the function file, which is expected to contain the function definition, is executed on every cold start, but not if the instance has already been initialized.

This should keep the listener active even after the function's execution has completed until that specific instance is running (which should be about [~30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934774/gcp-cloud-function-instance-lifetime)). Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

let listener = false;

// Store all utmLinks in global scope
let utmLinks: any[] = [];

const initListeners = () => {
  functions.logger.info("Initializing listeners");
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("utmLinks")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change) => {
        functions.logger.info(change.type, "document received");
        switch (change.type) {
          case "added":
            utmLinks.push({ id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() });
            break;

          case "modified":
            const index = utmLinks.findIndex(
              (link) => link.id === change.doc.id
            );
            utmLinks[index] = { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() };
            break;

          case "removed":
            utmLinks = utmLinks.filter((link) => link.id !== change.doc.id);

          default:
            break;
        }
      });
    });
  return;
};


// The HTTPs function
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    if (!listener) {
      // Cold start, no listener active
      initListeners();
      listener = true;
    } else {
      functions.logger.info("Listeners already initialized");
    }

    response.send(JSON.stringify(utmLinks, null, 2));
  }
);
```

This example stores all UTM links in an array in global scope which won't be persisted in new instances but you won't have to query each link for every request. The `onSnapshot()` listener will keep `utmLinks` updated.

The output in logs should be:

[image]

---

If you want to persist this data permanently and prevent querying in every cold start, then you can try using [Google Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) that keeps running unlike Cloud functions that timeout eventually.

Comment: Adding to this: if you set your ```minInstances=1```, the function will be persisted in memory much longer, keeping the Global Scope alive even longer.  But NOT guaranteed "forever".

Comment: as I have stated in my question, my second approach was to try this. the problem of this approach is my website does not recieve a lot of requests, so I would have a lot of cold starts, which means longer response times. An optimal solution I thought of, is to add a cache header and deliver the redirection from the cdns, however, I have a logic which increases visitor count in the database for each request, so I want every request to hit my server.

Comment: @Adnan in my opinion, a VM instance can be useful if you don't want cold starts if you don't have many requests. Like a `e2-micro` instance should be enough too which essentially falls in free tier.